# Linearity of the normal probability plot

Tags: normality-assumption

When you make the normal probability plot, the plot may have curved bounds. Then the plot should be roughly linear **and** the data must lie within the bounds provided by software. In the  examples I have seen the normal was rejected because some data points were not within the bounds. Can you provide an example where the data is between the bounds, but not linear?

Comment: Sorry if this seems like a stupid question, but what do you call "bounds provided by software"?

Comment: Something to do with computational limits, as with the max. number of obs/vars dealt by different versions of Stata SE/IC/MP perhaps?

Comment: @chl @Fr. ["Some normal probability plots include bounds that depict the natural variability one could see in data even when it comes from a normal distribution".](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~wrstephe/stat403/probplot.html)

Comment: Those curved bounds are just a formalization of "how linear": if your data were completely linear on the quantile-quantile plot, it would match the expectation exactly, which is extremely unlikely and suggests manipulation. So you should allow for a slightly ragged line, and those bounds are the result of one way to define the "fat marker" that you can smooth the line with. If the data were naturally curved but within the bounds, a larger sample would push the bounds closer to each other until the curve no longer fit inside.

Answer (score 2):

This is a synthetic example. Here the data are close to q1=q2 but stepwise rather than linear. The example draws a sample from a normal distribution (right panel) then rounds the numbers (left panel).

```
set.seed(100)
x=rnorm(100, sd=3)
par(mfrow=(c(1, 2)))
qqnorm(round(x))
qqnorm(x)
```

[image: Normal Q-Q Plot]